# When to use Qualifier and Primary in Spring

Tags: spring, annotations

I have read that @Qualifier can be used in Injection phase whereas @Primary is used in Configuration phase. Am still unclear when to use which.

Also I have below doubts

- can @Primary and @Qualifier be used together? if yes does @Qualifier take precedence?
- can @Primary be used with @Autowired?
- How is the Injection phase different from Configuration phase, this in respect to Spring beans

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`@Primary` indicates that a bean should be given preference when multiple candidates
are qualified to autowire a single-valued dependency.

`@Qualifier` indicates specific bean should be autowired when there are multiple candidates.

For example, we have two beans both implement the same interface.

```
public interface BeanInterface {

    String getName();
}


public class Bean1 implements BeanInterface {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "bean 1";
    }
}


public class Bean2 implements BeanInterface {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "bean2";
    }
}
```

Here is our service.

```
@Service
public class BeanService {

    @Autowired
    private BeanInterface bean;
}
```

And our configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean("bean1")
    public BeanInterface bean1() {
        return new Bean1();
    }

    @Bean("bean2")
    public BeanInterface bean2() {
        return new Bean2();
    }
}
```

When Spring starts, it will find there are two beans("bean1" and "bean2") both can be autowired to `BeanService` since they implement the same interface `BeanInterface`. It reports an error in my Idea.

```
Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'BeanInterface' type.
Beans: bean1   (Config.java) 
bean2   (Config.java)
```

And without a hint, Spring does not know which one to use.

So in our case, when we add `@Primary` to `Config.bean1()`.

```
@Bean("bean1")
@Primary
public BeanInterface bean1() {
    return new Bean1();
}
```

It tells Spring, "when you find more than one beans that both can be autowired, please use the **primary one** as your first choose." So, Spring will pick `bean1` to autowire to `BeanService`.

Here is another way to autowire `bean1` to `BeanService` by using `@Qualifier` in `BeanService.class`.

```
@Service
public class BeanService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("bean1")
    private BeanInterface bean;
}
```

`@Qualifier` will tell Spring, "no matter how many beans you've found, **just use the one I tell you.**"

So you can find both `@Qualifier` and `@Primary` are telling Spring to use the specific bean when multiple candidates are qualified to autowire. But `@Qualifier` is more specific and has high priority. So when both `@Qualifier` and `@Primary` are found, `@Primary` will be ignored.

Here is the test.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean("bean1")
    @Primary
    public BeanInterface bean1() {
        return new Bean1();
    }

    @Bean("bean2")
    public BeanInterface bean2() {
        return new Bean2();
    }
}

@Service
public class BeanService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("bean2")
    private BeanInterface bean;

    @PostConstruct
    public void test() {
        String name = bean.getName();
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

The output is "bean2".

Comment: Wow, you have cleared all my doubts..Many thanks for the crystal clear example! How frequently do we use annotation based Configuration as opposed to XML, is xml based configuration better or scores over programmatic?

Comment: It's a trend to use java config since programmatic config is much more convenient and clearly.

Comment: You don't have to mark the class definition with `@Component` since you already annotated the method name in the configuration class with `@Bean`, which is enough in this case. Great answer though!

Comment: @securecurve yes you are right. I've modified it, thank you for pointing out that.

Comment: Does `@Qualifer` take precedence over `@Profile` as well?

Comment: "So when both `@Qualifier` and `@Primary` are found, `@Primary` will be ignored." This is not a valid assumption, you can use both and primary will be injected when there is no qualifier.

Comment: @aydinugur I think you are talking about a special situation. In my opinion it is a wrong usage which we should avoid. Anyway, I didn't think of that, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5):

Also, need to remember that `@Qualifier` as bigger priority then `@Primary`, that's means that it's waste to define both of the annotations.

`@Primary` means default implementation, while `@Qualifier` is the specific implementation.

You can review my blog I wrote regarding this annotations -
https://shaikezam.com/article/spring_qualifier

Comment: Please add a quote from the above post in case the link goes dead in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @Qualifier takes precedence.
Yes we can user @Primary and @Autowired together.

@Configuration Class related to Application Context which can be use to configure application level configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To access beans with the same type we usually use `@Qualifier(“beanName”)` annotation. We apply it at the injection point along with `@Autowired`. In our case, we select the beans at the configuration phase so `@Qualifier` can't be applied here.

To resolve this issue Spring offers the `@Primary` annotation along with `@Bean` annotation.

[Source](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-primary)