# Need to create two objects of one interface in one Java class

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, java-11

I have a problem, I have an interface and that interface is implemented in two classes. I need to created two objects of one interface. So, one object for class aCluud and other for bCluud, and can access method through the object. Example:

Interface:

```
public interface clousservice{
    public void getA();
    public void getB();
}
```

Classes:

```
public class aCluud implements clousservice{
    public void getA(){
        //some Java code
    }

    public void getB() {
        //some Java code
    }
}

public class bCluud implements clousservice{
    public void getA(){
        //some Java code
    }

    public void getB() {
        //some Java code
    }
}
```

Access interface in different classes

```
public class task {
    private final  clousservice service;

    public task(clousservice service){
        this.service = service
    }
}
```

When I start a server, I get below message

> Parameter 0 of constructor in au.com.task.Task required a single bean,
> but 2 were found:

How I can achieve this functionality? For this I am using Java 11 and Spring Boot.

Comment: This is because Spring doesn't know which bean to inject, you can use @Qualifier annotation to avoid this problem.

Comment: if I want to create two obj. One from acloud and another for bcloud,So how I can do that?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56642356/when-to-use-qualifier-and-primary-in-spring