# What is the need for primary if Qualifier can do the work?

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, backend, autowired

I understand that using @Primary gives a default choice. But what is the harm in always specifying your preference using @Qualifier?
As, in case if both are used then priority goes to @Qualifier.
And if there is nothing wrong then Why is even @Primary needed?

Suppose i have a piece of code lets say :

```
@Component
@Primary
public class FooFormatter implements Formatter {
    //...
}

@Component
public class BarFormatter implements Formatter {
    //...
}
```

if i want to inject any if the above two i can always do:

```
@Qualifier("FooFormatter")
@Autowired
private Formatter formatter;

//OR

@Qualifier("BarFormatter")
@Autowired
private Formatter formatter;
```

Comment: Maybe this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56642356/when-to-use-qualifier-and-primary-in-spring and this article: https://www.javaguides.net/2023/07/spring-qualifier-vs-primary-annotations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Primary` allows you to override a bean that would be present by default.
This can be used to override a default/fallback implementation with something more specific.

Example use case: have a default (maybe even no-op) implementation, and a special implementation activated by a configuration property (with `@ConditionalOnProperty`).

With `@Qualifier`, you're dealing with **known variants** of an bean, and pick an appropriate one. Example: differently configured `RestTemplate` beans, one for each system you connect to.